# How to correctly import + loop through imported vars

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to replace this ugly block:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGILL, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal_handler)
```

with this:

```
import signal
for sig in (SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE):
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
```

Unfortunately python throws:

```
File "./mysuperfile.py", line 107, in <module>
   for sig in (SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE):
       NameError: name 'SIGINT' is not defined
```

I also tried to do

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE
```

.. but this throws:

```
  File "./mysuperfile.py", line 108, in <module>
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

Question: what is the correct syntax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do:

```
import signal
for sig in ("SIGINT", "SIGTERM", "SIGQUIT", "SIGILL", "SIGPIPE"):
    sig = getattr(signal,sig)
    signal.signal(sig, signal_handler)
```

When you do a simple `import signal`, all of your signal handles can be found in the current namespace as `signal.SIGNALNAME` (e.g. `signal.SIGQUIT`).  This is the same thing as:

```
for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGQUIT, ...):
    signal.signal(sig,signal_handler)
```

---

Of course, you can import them directly into your current namespace as you were trying:

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE
```

But then the `signal` function is known as simply `signal` (not `signal.signal`) in the current namespace.  So, using that import, you could do:

```
for sig in (SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE):
    signal(sig, signal_handler)
```

However, I find that to be less clear.  Is `signal` the module or the function?  Maybe it isn't too hard to figure out (after all, you can't *call* a module), but the other way it's obvious immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import signal from itself, but you can import both separately.

```
import signal
from signal import SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGPIPE
```

Comment: Yikes! both your and mgilson's answers are correct... and SO will only let me mark one. Regardless, thank you!